How to enable the display of hints for OpenCV in PyCharm?
I am trying to configure PyCharm to work with OpenCV. First, I installed OpenCV with cuda support using cmake. Next, I checked that cv2 is being imported and checked that the test code is working. But I came across the fact that PyCharm does not give hints for cv2.
I tried adding the path to /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cv2/ to the interpreter.
But nothing has changed.Installing the opencv-python package causes cuda to be unsupported. What should I do? I will be glad of any information.
P.S. I'm sorry if I violated the rules of registration, this is my first question.
Unfortunately, I don't think any solution can help me (opencv autocomplete not working on pycharm). I immediately removed the options for upgrading to a specific version, since I managed to install opencv with cuda only on version 4.7.0. Also, I do not have a site-packages directory, instead cv2 is located in dist-packages, but even in it I did not find the file cv2.abi3.so or cv2.pyd. I was interested in the last option with the creation of a virtual conda environmen, because this case is closest to me. I will be glad of any advice!

This question is similar to: opencv autocomplete not working on pycharm. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
